# Scala Packrat Parsers, error messages and referential transparency

Tags: scala, parsing, functional-programming, parser-combinators

I'm trying to parse boolean expressions into an `Expr` tree using Scala's Packrat parsers from `scala-parser-combinators`.

```
  sealed trait Expr
  case class Term(term: String) extends Expr
  case class And(x: Expr, y: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Or(x: Expr, y: Expr) extends Expr
```

```
aaa and bbb          --> And(Term(aaa),Term(bbb))
aaa and bbb or ccc   --> Or(And(Term(aaa),Term(bbb)),Term(ccc))
aaa and (bbb or ccc) --> And(Term(aaa),Or(Term(bbb),Term(ccc)))
```

This grammar seems to work perfectly fine:

```
object Parsing extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {

  override val skipWhitespace = false

  val validIdentifiers = List("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")

  lazy val term: PackratParser[Term] = """\s*""".r ~> """\w+""".r flatMap { identifier =>
    if (validIdentifiers.contains(identifier))
      success(Term(identifier))
    else
      err(s"expected one of: $validIdentifiers")
  }

  lazy val and: PackratParser[And] =
    expr ~ """\s+and\s+""".r ~ (term | parensExpr) ^^ { case e1 ~ _ ~ e2 => And(e1, e2) }

  lazy val or: PackratParser[Or] =
    expr ~ """\s+or\s+""".r ~ (term | parensExpr) ^^ { case e1 ~ _ ~ e2 => Or(e1, e2) }

  lazy val parensExpr: PackratParser[Expr] = """\s*\(""".r ~> expr <~ """\s*\)""".r

  lazy val expr: PackratParser[Expr] =
    term ||| and ||| or ||| parensExpr

  lazy val root: PackratParser[Expr] =
    phrase(expr)

  def parseExpr(input: String): ParseResult[Expr] =
    parse(root, new PackratReader(new CharSequenceReader(input)))
}
```

But error messages are sometimes.... bad.
If the parser finds an invalid identifier on the left-hand side of an `and`, it'll correctly tell us so.

```
println(parseExpr("invalidIdentifier and aaa"))


[1.18] error: expected one of: List(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd)
invalidIdentifier and aaa
                 ^
```

But if it finds an invalid identifier on the **right**-hand side of an `and`, it'll give us this misleading error message.

```
println(parseExpr("aaa and invalidIdentifier"))

[1.4] failure: end of input expected
aaa and invalidIdentifier
   ^
```

I'm pretty sure this happens because `expr` will try all 4 options: `and`/`or`/`parensExpr` will fail, but `term` will succeed with just `Term("aaa")`.

Then, `root`'s `phrase` will kick in and check whether there's any input left to consume, and fail because there is: " and invalidIdentifier".

---

So I thought, I'll push `phrase` one level down. In other words, I changed this:

```
  lazy val expr: PackratParser[Expr] =
    term ||| and ||| or ||| parensExpr

  lazy val root: PackratParser[Expr] =
    phrase(expr)
```

Into this:

```
  lazy val expr: PackratParser[Expr] =
    term ||| and ||| or ||| parensExpr

  lazy val root: PackratParser[Expr] =
    phrase(term) ||| phrase(and) ||| phrase(or) ||| phrase(parensExpr)
```

Now, all 4 options should fail, but we should see `and`'s error message because `and` consumed more input than the other 3 options

I'm now getting better error messages BUT, to my surprise, some previously valid inputs are now invalid!

```
println(parseExpr("aaa or bbb"))

[1.4] failure: string matching regex '\s+and\s+' expected but ' ' found
aaa or bbb
   ^
```

```
println(parseExpr("aaa and bbb or ccc"))

[1.12] failure: end of input expected
aaa and bbb or ccc
           ^
```

I don't understand why.

---

In fact, even just a simpler, trivial change such as this:

```
  // before
  lazy val root: PackratParser[Expr] =
    phrase(expr)

  // after
  lazy val root: PackratParser[Expr] =
    phrase(term ||| and ||| or ||| parensExpr)
```

... breaks previously valid inputs.

How come? Shouldn't these two definitions of `root` be equivalent? Are these parsers not referentially transparent?

More importantly, how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Not familiar with Packrat but there is a really amazing parsing library with similar grammar for Scala: fastparse. If the refactoring is not that much of an overhead, please have a look at it. I might save you some headache as it has a better documentation. PS: This problem is solvable there.

Comment: @lprakashv I was actually using fastparse when I began trying to implement this, but then realized fastparse isn't suitable for these grammars. I need the grammar to be left-associative (i.e. `x and y and z` should be parsed as `(x and y) and z` rather than `x and (y and z)`), and fastparse recurses forever on left-recursive grammars, and overflows the stack. Packrat parsers, on the other hand, use memoization to avoid overflowing the stack and are perfect for left-recursive grammars.

Comment: Here's someone who had the exact same problem as me with fastparse->packrat parsers: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/with-input-from-string/4737/20

Comment: I think left-recursive grammars can be transformed with a series of steps to remove the left-recursion, but I'm not sure how to do that either :/

Comment: Here's a step-by-step algorithm for removing left-recursion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion
Note: It might lead to slightly uglier trees in your case (since you mentioned left-associativity)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the following errors with the exact code you posted, I believe these are the expected error messages?:

```scala
@ println(Parsing.parseExpr("invalidIdentifier and aaa"))
[1.18] error: expected one of: List(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd)

invalidIdentifier and aaa
                 ^


@ println(Parsing.parseExpr("aaa and invalidIdentifier"))
[1.26] error: expected one of: List(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd)

aaa and invalidIdentifier
                         ^
```

I'm using ammonite repl with ivy imported Scala Parser Combinators library:

```
import $ivy.`org.scala-lang.modules::scala-parser-combinators:1.1.2`
```

Maybe a library version issue?

Comment: That's weird, I just tried it on ammonite as well and I get the `failure: end of input expected` error... here's a full log of my ammonite shell: https://gist.github.com/dcastro/18b586421b0d12fbeda0c69e56df6912

Comment: Just guessing here, but, try changing "aaa" to "aaaaa" in the list of valid identifiers and in the input string. Maybe if the match is longer, then the `|||` will give it higher precedence.

Comment: Which version of the parser-combinators library are you using?

Comment: Same as yours, I even copy-pasted your ivy command. Can you replicate the commands in my log?

Comment: Hey, I actually tried this with `... extends App ...` which is breaking for me! My code actually is like: `object Parsing extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {...`

Comment: Yea, I removed the `extends App` as well, I was getting null ref exceptions when using `extends App` in the ammonite repl.